# MS Word 2010 VBA - how to parse non-latin characters?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a VBA script that prints out the word frequency in a document.

```
Sub WordFrequency()


Const maxwords = 9000          'Maximum unique words allowed
Dim SingleWord As String       'Raw word pulled from doc
Dim Words(maxwords) As String  'Array to hold unique words
Dim Freq(maxwords) As Integer  'Frequency counter for unique words
Dim WordNum As Integer         'Number of unique words
Dim ByFreq As Boolean          'Flag for sorting order
Dim ttlwds As Long             'Total words in the document
Dim Excludes As String         'Words to be excluded
Dim Found As Boolean           'Temporary flag
Dim j, k, l, Temp As Integer   'Temporary variables
Dim ans As String              'How user wants to sort results
Dim tword As String            '

' Set up excluded words
Excludes = "[the][a][of][is][to][for][by][be][and][are]"

' Find out how to sort
ByFreq = True
ans = InputBox("Sort by WORD or by FREQ?", "Sort order", "WORD")
If ans = "" Then End
If UCase(ans) = "WORD" Then
    ByFreq = False
End If

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
System.Cursor = wdCursorWait
WordNum = 0
ttlwds = ActiveDocument.Words.Count

' Control the repeat
For Each aword In ActiveDocument.Words
    SingleWord = Trim(LCase(aword))
    'Out of range?
    If SingleWord < "a" Or SingleWord > "z" Then
        SingleWord = ""
    End If
    'On exclude list?
    If InStr(Excludes, "[" & SingleWord & "]") Then
        SingleWord = ""
    End If
    If Len(SingleWord) > 0 Then
        Found = False
        For j = 1 To WordNum
            If Words(j) = SingleWord Then
                Freq(j) = Freq(j) + 1
                Found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If Not Found Then
            WordNum = WordNum + 1
            Words(WordNum) = SingleWord
            Freq(WordNum) = 1
        End If
        If WordNum > maxwords - 1 Then
            j = MsgBox("Too many words.", vbOKOnly)
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
    ttlwds = ttlwds - 1
    StatusBar = "Remaining: " & ttlwds & ", Unique: " & WordNum
Next aword

' Now sort it into word order
For j = 1 To WordNum - 1
    k = j
    For l = j + 1 To WordNum
        If (Not ByFreq And Words(l) < Words(k)) _
          Or (ByFreq And Freq(l) > Freq(k)) Then k = l
    Next l
    If k <> j Then
        tword = Words(j)
        Words(j) = Words(k)
        Words(k) = tword
        Temp = Freq(j)
        Freq(j) = Freq(k)
        Freq(k) = Temp
    End If
    StatusBar = "Sorting: " & WordNum - j
Next j

' Now write out the results
tmpName = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName
Documents.Add Template:=tmpName, NewTemplate:=False
Selection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.ClearAll

With Selection
    For j = 1 To WordNum
        .TypeText Text:=Trim(Str(Freq(j))) _
          & vbTab & Words(j) & vbCrLf
    Next j
End With
System.Cursor = wdCursorNormal
j = MsgBox("There were " & Trim(Str(WordNum)) & _
  " different words ", vbOKOnly, "Finished")
```

End Sub

However, this VBA script is not picking up non-latin characters in the document.

I am using Arial Unicode MS and another unicode font

What do I need in the macro to pick up these words?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't work with this...

```
If SingleWord < "a" Or SingleWord > "z" Then
    SingleWord = ""
End If
```

Remove that, and you should at least see non-Latin words. Beyond that, it's more a question of what you are trying to filter out. If it's stuff like "'words' starting with a digit or a punctuation mark" then you probably need to have a look through the Unicode tables and work out a better set of things to filter out (bearing in mind that some transliterated scripts may even use digits at the beginnings of words).